# How to setup Aftek RtmpLib in XCode 4.6.2 project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, rtmp

I have difficulties using [Aftek RtmpLib](http://www.aftek.com/afteklab/aftek-iphone-RTMP-library.shtml) library in my XCode 4.6.2 project. There are two libraries - one for the simulator and one for the device. I try to follow their instructions as well as other instructions that I found on the forums. I've got 2 basic errors when I try different build with the device library and simulator library:

1. Error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>
> ```
> ".objc_class_name_NSFileManager", referenced from:
> pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in RtmpLibSim.a(RtmpLib.o)
>
> ".objc_class_name_NSObject", referenced from:
> pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in RtmpLibSim.a(RtmpLib.o)
>
> ".objc_class_name_NSString", referenced from:
> pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in RtmpLibSim.a(RtmpLib.o)
> ```

1. Error (when I try to use the object):

> ```
> "._OBJC_CLASS_$_RtmpLib", referenced from:
> objc0ckass-ref in ViewController.o
> ```

When I include only the `RtmpLibSim.a(simulator)` I get both errors.

When I include only the `RtmpLibDivice.a(device)` I get only the second error.

Is there someone with more expiriance in iOS development to help me with this issue please? I'm asking specially for a XCode 4.6.2 project, preferably a "step by step" type of answer since I'm new to iOS development.

Comment: I am having same problem dude. I also eager to hear answer.

Comment: did u found the solution...?